# Serialization for Rcpp exposed class

Tags: c++, r, serialization, rcpp

I've written a C++ class in an R package that I expose to the R namespace with `RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS` and `RCPP_MODULE`.

Everything works great:

```
> index
An object of class "Index"
Slot "index":
C++ object <0x9cd4810> of class 'DB' <0xfd66220>
```

but if `saveRDS(index, 'DB.rds')` it does not save the actual object just the address. In turn it is casted as invalid when I load the `DB.rds` in a new session.

Is it possible to write a custom serialization method that could work transparently with `saveRDS` ?

Comment: "Maybe". You have the start address, you can work out the length. I don't know if you can re-instantiate an object that way.

Comment: That would not work for data that is located in the heap. So the way I see it, my best bet would be to write my own serialization function and store it as a vector on the object. But this is not transparent.

Comment: You probably have to be in R's memory pool anyway.  Short answer: we have said for all these it can't be done (easily).  That probably still holds, but then again with _sufficient_ error you potentially could.  Will it be worth it? Dunno.

Comment: Depending on how complex your object is, it may not be as difficult as you imagine.  One approach would be to convert all your class members to the equivalent R data type, and return it as an R list from Rcpp.

Comment: Is there a hook that I can define at my object so that the conversion happens via the `readRDS` and `saveRDS` calls?