# Saving a model, which utilizes external pointers to C++ in R

Tags: r

In this case, save or saveRD commands do not work. And it saves a model with null pointers which no longer work. For instance, if we run the following code how can we save the model such that I can regenerate it in new Rstadio? If you use the save or saveRD, you will be faced with null in external pointers when you load the saved model.

```
library(fastrtext)
data("train_sentences")
data("test_sentences")
texts <- tolower(train_sentences[,"text"])
tmp_file_txt <- tempfile()
tmp_file_model <- tempfile()
writeLines(text = texts, con = tmp_file_txt)
execute(commands = c("skipgram", "-input", tmp_file_txt, "-output", tmp_file_model, "-verbose", 1))
model <- load_model(tmp_file_model)
```

Comment: I see you've already commented there, but for context for anyone else looking at the question [here's an issue link on github](https://github.com/pommedeterresautee/fastrtext/issues/32) where the creator says one *"can save it through R using the command line (-output option)*" but doesn't provide additional detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think this is possible for classes exposed by Rcpp. See [this other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50582388/serialization-for-rcpp-exposed-class) which had comments from [@DirkEdelbuettel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143305/dirk-eddelbuettel). However, you’ve already got the model saved on disk, so can’t you just use a permanent path (not `tempfile()`) and then call `load_model` each time?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works for me. I edited the github issue and linked it to here.